# set equality using distributive property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I want to show $(A\setminus B) \cap C=(A\cap C)\setminus B$

What I've done is define $(A \setminus B)$ as $A\cap \bar B$. Then
\begin{align*} 
(A \setminus B) \cap C &= (A\cap \bar B)\cap C \\
& = (A \cap C)\cap (\bar B \cap C), \ \ \ \text{ by the distributive law} \\
& = (A\cap C) \cap (\bar B) \\ &= (A\cap C)\setminus B
\end{align*}
is this correct?

Comment: You are not using the distributive law here (carefully look at the use of $\cup$ and $\cap$ in the distributive laws to spot the difference). However, the line in your proof mentioning the distributive law works by $C\cap C= C$, *commutativity* and *associativity* of $\cap$.

Comment: What is problematic, though, is the step that $\bar B\cap C=\bar B$. This isn't true in general.

Comment: The argument as given is incorrect, because $\overline{B}\cap C= \overline{B}$ is false in general. But you don't need that. Why not use associativity and commutativity of the intersection, as Vsotvep suggests?

Comment: @Vsotvep . It IS correct, just unclear, as $(A\cap \bar B)\cap C=(A\cap \bar B)\cap C\cap C=(A\cap C)\cap (\bar B\cap C)$. It would be simpler and clearer to write $(A\cap \bar B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\cap\bar  B$ because $\cap$ is commutative and associative.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin. See my comment above.

Comment: It is more usual to write $B^c $ for the complement of $B$ because $\bar B$ has other uses, especially in topology.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The conclusion is correct, so of course an argument can be fixed to justify it. But what you propose is not, IMHO, a "clarification" of what the OP wrote, but rather a rewriting of it.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I never stated it isn't correct? Of course $\cap$ distributes over $\cap$ as well, so OP could've been aware of this, but I find it more likely that OP made a (harmless) mistake interpreting the distributive laws that they found in their book / notes / lecture.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use associativity and commutativity of intersection:
\begin{align*} 
(A \setminus B) \cap C &= (A\cap \bar B)\cap C \\
& = A \cap (\bar B \cap C) \qquad \text{ by associativity} \\
& = A \cap (C \cap \bar B) \qquad \text{ by commutativity} \\
& = (A\cap C) \cap \bar B \qquad \text{ by associativity}\\ 
&= (A\cap C)\setminus B
\end{align*}